# Python 2.7 intentional use of .items over .iteritems

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

Looking at the source of [`collections.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py) I see that `.items` is used instead of `.iteritems` in some instances, which I assume as intentional being part of Python's source code.

eg. in `update` (removed comments), `.iteritems` is used

```
 def update(self, iterable=None, **kwds):
   520 
   521         if iterable is not None:
   522             if isinstance(iterable, Mapping):
   523                 if self:
   524                     self_get = self.get
   525                     for elem, count in iterable.iteritems():
   526                         self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + count
   527                 else:
   528                     super(Counter, self).update(iterable) # fast path when counter is empty
   529             else:
   530                 self_get = self.get
   531                 for elem in iterable:
   532                     self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + 1
   533         if kwds:
   534             self.update(kwds)
```

but in `__add__` and other operations with `Counter`s `.items` is used

```
   590     def __add__(self, other):
   597         if not isinstance(other, Counter):
   598             return NotImplemented
   599         result = Counter()
   600         for elem, count in self.items():
   601             newcount = count + other[elem]
   602             if newcount > 0:
   603                 result[elem] = newcount
   604         for elem, count in other.items():
   605             if elem not in self and count > 0:
   606                 result[elem] = count
   607         return result
```

I understand it would be faster to use `.items` the case of small dictionaries, but you can't trust they will always be small, or is this a guess being made by Python? I really don't understand why they wouldn't just use `.iteritems` in every case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will guess myself that this was simply a bug that went unnoticed. The `Counter` class seems to have been hastily created.

eg. `Counter` doesn't contain many inplace methods such as `__iadd__` and `__isub__`.

Which make it inefficient to continuously use

```
c = Counter()
for other in list_of_counters:
    c += other
```

Nonetheless, these were added in [Python 3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/collections/__init__.py). There doesn't seem to be any reason why they shouldn't have been implemented originally, probably for the same reason as this.